# Get "301 Moved Permanently" on .load jQuery call

Tags: jquery, symfony

I'm calling a Symfony function in this way:

```
$("#product-stock").load(Routing.generate('stock_new', { cid: company_id} ));
```

The `Routing.generate()` method from FOSJsRoutingBundle returns this URL:

```
http://devserver/app_dev.php/stock/new/1/
```

Which is right and should be processed by this function:

```
/**
 * Display a form to create new stock
 * 
 * @Route("/stock/new/{cid}", name="stock_new")
 * @Method("GET")
 */
public function newAction(Request $request) {
    die('Entre' . $request->request->get('cid'));
}
```

But I get:

> 301 Moved Permanently 210ms

Does any have a idea what is causing this or what is happening? I spent several hours trying to get this solve without success.

PS: The route definition is unique and doesn't exists any other method with that route

Comment: It looks like the Routing.generate() is giving you a url to a page that then redirects you to another page, returning a 301 status code which would be an error to jQuery. you need to load a url that isn't doing a redirect.

Comment: @KevinB the URL returned by Routing.generate() is find, I check in source before call it and it's supposed that if I call the `/stock/new/1/` that matches with `* @Route("/stock/new/{cid}", name="stock_new")` sincerely I don't know where is the problem, Google also not help much

Comment: The status code you are getting says it all. The url you are requesting from is a redirect. jQuery can't handle redirects.

Comment: @KevinB apparently but is not, if you notice the URL should be processed by the function in the controller called `newAction()` as this match the route called, any idea for where to look at? I

Comment: I can't really tell any further than what i've already told you without seeing the page with my own eyes. Everything you've presented thus far suggests that `http://devserver/app_dev.php/stock/new/1/` is redirecting somewhere else.

Comment: Route behind firewall?